# How to get the price as a number from a website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, floating-point, getattribute

I am creating a bot that would automate my work and copy particular values from a particular website. Everything works fine but the last lines of my code that says w.text produces an outcome which is text and I need a number. Each element that I need the value of looks like this after inspection:

```
<span class="good">€25,217.65</span>
```

How do I get the value as a number instead of as a text? I tried w.value or w.get_attribute('value) but it doesn't work.
Here is my program (excluding downloads of libraries and files)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)   
driver.get('https://seabass-admin.igp.cloud/')   
# waiting for login table to load
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="email"]'))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

#entering sensitive info
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(pwx.em)                                  # login details
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(pwx.pw)                               # password 
details
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="appContainer"]/div/form/button').click()       # click sign in

# waiting for page to load
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//* 
[@id="testing"]/section/section[4]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/span'))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

# getting info from the page
w = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="testing"]/section/section[4]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/span')
cell = outcome['import']
cell[withdrawal_cell].value = w.text
```

Comment: so you are getting this value - `w.text` as `€25,217.65` ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared:

```
<span class="good">€25,217.65</span>
```

The text **€25,217.65** is the *innerHTML*.

So, you can extract the text *€25,217.65* using either:

- `w.get_attribute("innerHTML")`
- *text* attribute.

Now to get the value **€25,217.65** as a number instead of text you need to:

- Remove the `€` and `,` character using `re.sub()`:

  ```
  import re

  string = "€25,217.65"
  my_string = re.sub('[€,]', '', string)
  ```
- Finally, to convert the *string* to *float* you need to pass the string as an argument to the `float()` as follows:

  ```
  my_number = float(my_string)
  ```

So the entire operation in a single line:

```
import re

string = "€25,217.65"       
print(float(re.sub('[€,]', '', string)))
```

Effectively, your line of code can be either of the following:

- Using *text* attribute:

  ```
  cell[withdrawal_cell].value = float(re.sub('[€,]', '', w.text))
  ```
- Using `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  cell[withdrawal_cell].value = float(re.sub('[€,]', '', w.get_attribute("innerHTML")))
  ```

Comment: I can easily get it as text, but I need it as a number - thats the whole point. Because when it saves all the values that I scrapped from the web, I need to then perform mathematical operations but at the moment I need to go into the file, manually change the format to a number from the text - only then I can proceed. I'm trying to automate everything so I need that number as a number - not as a text

Comment: @EllieBiessek Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some of Python's built in functions for that:

1. [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove any leading or trailing '€' character, then
2. [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to remove ',' (replace it with an empty string '')

Specifically:

```
str_w = w.text  # this is the '€25,217.65' string
digits=str_w.strip('€').replace(',','')     # use the functions above to get number-like string
cell[withdrawal_cell].value = float(digits)   # convert to float number
```

Comment: getting an error message 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: You need to apply that to a string type object, that's `w.text` (this line `str_w = w.text`) rather than `w` (webelement).