# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' with multiplying

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I use a screen scraper to get the value of my account balance, I would like to get 10% of that value but it gives this error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. The code looks like this:

```
account_balance = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/main/section/div/div[1]/section[2]/button[1]/span[1]") 
account_balance_value = account_balance.get_attribute("title")
```

The value that it gives right now is

```
print(account_balance_value) 
0,10
```

So I change it to this

```
account_balance_value = account_balance_value.replace(',', '.') 
print(account_balance_value)  
0.10
```

When I print this it gives the error:

```
print(account_balance_value * 0.1)   
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-536a3835612f> in <module>
----> 1 print(account_balance_value * 0.1)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

If I just run this it's fine

```
print(0.10 * 0.1) 
0.010000000000000002
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: the variable account_balance_value seems to be a string. Try converting it to float with float(account_balance_value).

Comment: Whats the output of `type(account_balance_value)`?

Answer (score 1):

[`get_attribute(attribute_name)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) would return a string. So `account_balance_value` is of type *string* hence further you can manipulate the string using `replace()` as:

```
account_balance_value = account_balance_value.replace(',', '.')
```

So by all possible means, through the line of code:

```
print(account_balance_value)
```

you are printing a *string* and you can't multiply the *string* `account_balance_value` with a *float* i.e. `0.1`

---

### Solution

You need to convert the *string* value within `account_balance_value` to a float using `float()` and then print the result as follows:

```
print(float(account_balance_value) * 0.1)
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291334/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float-in-python-3/60296021#60296021)
- [How to get the price as a number from a website using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406791/how-to-get-the-price-as-a-number-from-a-website-using-selenium-and-python/62407636#62407636)

Answer (score 0):

Your `account_balance_value` seems to be a string. Try

```
print(float(account_balance_value) * 0.1)
```

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your variable `account_balance_value` is a string.

Try adding:

```
account_balance_value = float(account_balance_value)
```

to convert it to a float, before running your other code.

If that also doesn't work, it could be because it contains a comma, so you will have to separate the two values before running that code.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the variable account_balance_value is of string type. For performing any mathematical operations you have to convert that variable to float type using the function float().

```
SYNTAX= float(variable name)
```

here,
`account_balance_value=float(account_balance_value)`  is the correction that has to be done.